# Is there an option to reduce the compiler output when converting AS to JS?

Tags: apache-royale

I'm using Apache Royale mxmljsc compiler to convert AS to JS and there is more information than I want to see in the output. I'm only interested in if it's successful or there are errors.

Is there a compiler argument I can set to reduce the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 0.9.6 has the following:

- Added -verbose compiler option to reduce console output by default.

It's now off by default.